# Size of a foreign key in bytes?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables where one references the other using a foreign key. I need to know what the size of that foreign key is, not the primary key itself but the entry in the column. So if we have two tables:

tb1

```
|id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY| name VARCHAR|
```

tb2

```
|id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY| info VARCHAR | tb1_id SERIAL REFERENCES tb1|
```

How big is `tb1_id` in bytes? Is it 32 bit like an integer? I could not find the answer in the spec or documentation for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A foreign key is not a magic "reference", it's a regular column that stores a value. With a foreign key constraint in place, it is simply enforced that the same value must also exists in a different table.

So it takes as much space as the data type for that column requires which should always be the same data type as the column it references.

As `serial` is a shortcut for an `integer` column, so `tb1_id` should be defined as `integer` as well. So the answer to "how big is tb_id" would be: 4 bytes (the size of an integer).

Postgres doesn't prevent you from using a different (but "compatible") data type though. In theory, `tb1_id` *could* (but shouldn't!) be defined as `bigint` which would then require 8 bytes of storage. But defining the columns referencing other columns with a different data type is a bad idea to begin with, so don't do that.

---

The foreign key constraint itself does not require any storage space in the involved tables themselves (They only require some the space in the system tables that is required to store the definition).

---

Note that a column that references a `serial` should **NOT** be defined as `serial`. If should be defined as `integer` (which is the real data type behind a `serial`).

This becomes more evident if you use identity columns (which are essentially the ANSI SQL standard syntax for a "serial").

The DDL for first table when used with an identity column would look like this:

```
create table tb1 
(
  id integer primary key generated by default as identity
);
```

And the second table would look like this:

```
create table tb2 
(
  id integer primary key generated by default as identity, 
  tb1_id integer references tb1
);
```

Would you use `tb1_id integer generated by default as identity` in the second table? Probably not, but that would be the same as using `tb1_id serial`

Comment: Yes of cause `tb1_id` is a `SERIAL`. BUT! Does it take up space in the persistently stored data? Meaning will it `|tb1| = 4 + 255` and `|tb2| = 4 + 255 + 4` or are there some data savings because it is "just" a reference? That is what I am after. :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. I don't think that there is space saving involved in this scenario. Foreign key constraint on a column is just a reference, but the value itself is still present in the referencing column.

Comment: @KamilGosciminsk okay damnit :)

Comment: The foreign key column should not be a `serial` column in the first place, it should just be an `integer`. Either way, the value is stored as normal, and the foreign key part is just an extra check. There's no magic space saving, because the reference needs to be able to hold every possible integer value, so it's always going to be at least as wide as an integer.

Comment: @LarsNielsen: I have added a more detailed explanation on what's wrong with defining a FK column as serial